# Upload and display images using thymeleaf and springboot

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload, spring-boot, thymeleaf

This is my upload image code in Spring Boot:

```
String root = ctx.getRealPath("/");
File dir = new File(root + File.separatorChar + "images");
if (!dir.exists())
    dir.mkdir();

String path = dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separatorChar
            + product.getProductName() + "."
            + file.getContentType().split("/")[1];
System.out.println(path);
File file1 = new File(path);
try {
    FileOutputStream fod = new FileOutputStream(file1);
    fod.write(file.getBytes());
    fod.close();
    product.setProductPicture("/images/" + product.getProductName()
            + "." + file.getContentType().split("/")[1]);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The uploading of files works fine, only problem with this code is that when i use `ctx.getRealPath("/")` it returns temporary location and when i restart the spring boot app i loose already existing files which was already uploaded as it creates a new temporary directory.

This causes some problem as i also have to display this pics on my site and now it returns "image not found error".

So I needed a solution which will allow me to upload files in a permanent location and serve files from there on the browser.

**Note:** I'm using thymeleaf for views.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. I created a new function which will only return `bytes[]` and sent as response body as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "image/{imageName}")
@ResponseBody
public byte[] getImage(@PathVariable(value = "imageName") String imageName) throws IOException {

    File serverFile = new File("/home/user/uploads/" + imageName + ".jpg");

    return Files.readAllBytes(serverFile.toPath());
}
```

And in html `<img alt="Image" th:src="@{image/userprofile}" width="250" height="250"/>`

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I did it.

Step 1: Create a uploads folder in your project directory.

[image]

Step 2: Create ResourceConfig file

```
    @Configuration
    public class ResourceConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/uploads/**").addResourceLocations("file:uploads/");
        }
    }
```

Step 3: Add your html thymleaf

```
<img th:src="@{'/uploads/' + ${someobject.someAttribute}}"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot. I have to do this but with an image storage in my db, as follows:

```
      @GetMapping("/muestra/{idproducto}")
  @ResponseBody
  public byte[] muestraImagen(Model model,
        //id of the product i need to show the picture
      @PathVariable("idproducto")Integer idproducto, HttpServletResponse response) {
        //object from database
    Productos producto = productosRepository.findByIdproducto(idproducto);
    logger.info("sal imagen yo te invoco");
    //return the attr of my object (blob)
    return producto.getArchivo();
  }
```

and in html:

```html
<img alt="Image" th:src="@{/tienda/productos/muestra/{id}(id=${producto.idproducto})}" width="250" height="250"/>
```